# Yii2 - Validate attribute with keys

Tags: php, validation, model-view-controller, yii2

I have a problem with attribute key validation.

In model I have property like:

```
public $_fileds = [];
```

and My view

```
  <?= $form->field($model, '_fileds[name]') ?>
  <?= $form->field($model, '_fileds[type]') ?>
```

I want to set "_fields[name]" as requierd field. For example I tried add to rules in model something like this:

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
    [['_fields[name]'], 'required']
 ];
}
```

but this not working :(

Does anyone have any solution?

Sorry for my not good English and thanks in advance for all solutions.

Comment: `_fields[name]` is not attribute name, so it will not work in validation rules. Is there any reason why you're using one array attribute for multiple fields instead of adding separate attributes for each field?

Comment: Yes, I want to add $_fields as json to table in mysql for example: [0 => ['name' => 'Email', 'type' => 'text'], 1 => ['name' => 'Password', 'type' => 'password']]

Comment: Can't you generate this JSON from multiple attributes after validation?

Comment: You can create one more model for perticular JSON format and describe json fields and in rules

Comment: but I want to do multiple field with index using the loop for. _fileds[0][name], _fileds[1][name], _fileds[2][name]. Do as you mentioned with the help of validator "each" or rather should I do collecting tabular input?

Comment: you can create array of that model

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own validation.

Remove: `public $_fileds = [];`

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
    [['_fields[name]'], 'validateName']
 ];
}
```

In same model class:

```
public function validateName():bool
    {
        ... your checks(if fails return false) ...
        return true;
    }
```

But there is one issue: if some of checks fails you, in normal cases, need to set error message using $this->addError() which will correctly work with attributes which are not array elements because as first element of `$this->addError()` you need to pass attribute name as string where '_fileds' is ok but '_fileds[name]' won't work. So you also need to find a way to return errors if they appear. Same issue with attribute labels and hints.